# How to run a database procedure after Siebel EIM job

Tags: database, function, stored-procedures, siebel

I would like to run a database procedure after a successful EIM job run to collect information and record historical changes.
How can I call this database procedure automatically without manual intervention.

BR
Hani

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the solution approach you take. If all has to be handeled within Sieber, the a workflow that creates the job, monitors it result and then proceeds with the second step seems to me to be feasible. An alternative would be to use a CI system like Jenkins/Automic to handle the orchestration part.